# How to add a column in MS Access using SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Everytime I try to add a column using ALTER and ADD COLUMN I am getting a syntax error.

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_1
```

```
ADD COLUMN EMP_PCT NUMBER(4,2),
```

```
ADD COLUMN PROJ_NUM CHAR(3);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with a `number` data type.  Perhaps you mean `decimal`:

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_1 ADD COLUMN EMP_PCT DECIMAL(5, 2);
```

You may also need two `ALTER TABLE` statements.  I am just not sure if MS Access allows two changes in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

For a numeric type you should use NUMERIC, not NUMBER, and for a text type you should use VARCHAR.